# Error moving large amounts of content

Tags: aem

Whenever I move large amounts of content (roughly 300 pages) via CQ within the siteadmin interface I consistently get an error message that pops up after roughly 10-15 minutes. It seems to happen like clockwork but the pages still move successfully and the references get updated. All the error says is "An Error Occurred" and I check the logs and there are no error messages that I can find. Any ideas why this error pops up in CQ and if this is a larger problem with my instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience this is just a timeout error from the javascript. The move is triggered by an ajax call which waits for a response. But if a few hundred pages are moved at once the response takes really long and after a few minutes the javascript gives up waiting for a response and throws this error.
The more CPU and memory your server has, the faster the move will take place which reduces the chance for this error to pop up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thomas very helpful. But if the javascript gives up waiting for a response and throws an error why would the pages still move successfully?

Comment: Because the server moves the pages without any further communication with the client. The client triggers the move on the server, the pages are then moved by the server while the connection between client and server is kept open. After all pages are moved the server uses the open connection and responds with an OK message. As Thomas already said, if the move takes a long time, the client assumes something went wrong, because it receives no acknowledgement from the server. Then the error message pops up. However, this doesn't mean that the server isn't still moving the pages.